# How to properly handle errors from PDO fetch()?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

The doc for error handling for fetch() seems unclear and I haven't found an answer anywhere after a lot of searching. A common usage model for fetch as shown in the doc is:

```
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

The PHP doc at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php says:

> In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.

What does "failure" mean? An error? A failure to fetch more rows? My question is: when fetch() returns FALSE, what is best practice to detect errors? It seems like after the loop I need to distinguish between an error case and the "no more rows" case.

Should I call $stmt->errorCode() and see if it's '00000' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch() will return false when there's no more data to be fetched. There could also be other case where there truly is a failure, e.g. mysql died or the connection was lost while doing the fetch loop. But generally speaking, that sort of "real" failure is fairly rare, and you'll most often get "false because there's no more data available".

If you're truly paranoid about writing error handling, then by all means, put an sql error code check after the while loop to catch the cases when something really did blow up.

Comment: +1 The only errors you should be concerned about here are when you run the query. ie your syntax is incorrect, names are mis-spelled malformed query etc..

Comment: @waygood: that'd be a failure on the `query()` call, not on fetch.

Comment: @Mark B: No snark intended but when you say "real failure is fairly rare" and "you'll most often get false because there's no more data", I hear "errors are fairly rare" and "you'll most often get success". That's true of most coding, no? Seems like most error handling is handling the rare case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added this to my code after my while() loop exits: if ( $sth->errorCode() !== '00000' ) { /* handle error here */ }. Done.

Comment: Doesn't work at all. My PDO randomly fails with `Empty row packet body`, `fetch()` returns `false` but the `errorCode` is the standard `00000` :(

Answer (score 5):

To handle query errors (sql errors not occurs on fetch) and more generaly PDO error you should try using `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.
Moreover the PdoStatement returned by `query()` implement Traversable , so you can skip the use of `fetch()` for simple query :

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.db');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // Set Errorhandling to Exception
    foreach($db->query("SELECT...") as $row)
    {
      //Do domething
    }
    $db = null; // "Disconnect"
}
catch (PDOException $err) {
   //Handling query/error
}
```

An execption will be thrown if query encounter an error (not fetch()).

Fetch will always return false when it reach the end of your result set.